# Oracle SQL to SFMC Date Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, sqlserver

Running a query to send email subscribers a +X day email. `FIRST_PROMO_SUBSCRIBE_DATE` is coming from Oracle which they say is not a compatible format with Salesforce SQL so I have;

```
select * from PROMO_SUBSCRIBERS
where 
(ORDER_ENGAGEMENT_LAST_DT > dateadd(day,-335,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)) 
or ORDER_ENGAGEMENT_LAST_DT is null)
and 
(ORDER_LAST_DT > dateadd(day,-1,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)) 
or order_last_dt is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to cast the Oracle dates to `date`.  Casting to `date` will also strip the time portion off of the `datetime` fields in T-SQL.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac77b/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE promo_subscribers 
    (
     emailaddress varchar(255)
     , ORDER_ENGAGEMENT_LAST_DT  varchar(15)
     , ORDER_LAST_DT  varchar(15)

    );

INSERT INTO promo_subscribers
(emailaddress, ORDER_ENGAGEMENT_LAST_DT, ORDER_LAST_DT)
VALUES
('test@example.com', '01-APR-98', '01-APR-16'),
('test@example.com', '01-MAY-98', '06-APR-16')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
emailaddress
, order_engagement_last_dt
, cast(order_engagement_last_dt as date) datecast1
, order_last_dt
, cast(order_last_dt as date) datecast2
, dateadd(day,-335, cast(getDate() as date)) datecast3
, dateadd(day,-1, cast(getDate() as date)) datecast4
from PROMO_SUBSCRIBERS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac77b/1/0)**:

```
|     emailaddress | order_engagement_last_dt |  datecast1 | order_last_dt |  datecast2 |  datecast3 |  datecast4 |
|------------------|--------------------------|------------|---------------|------------|------------|------------|
| test@example.com |                01-APR-98 | 1998-04-01 |     01-APR-16 | 2016-04-01 | 2015-05-08 | 2016-04-06 |
| test@example.com |                01-MAY-98 | 1998-05-01 |     06-APR-16 | 2016-04-06 | 2015-05-08 | 2016-04-06 |
```